# Bing Maps How to check if a point is inside the bounds of the map?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, bing-maps

My purpose is to get the map boundaries and then to loop over my collection and to check which points are inside the boundaries.

So the first step is getting the map boundaries:

```
LocationRect bounds = map.Bounds;
Location northwest = bounds.Northwest;
Location southeast = bounds.Southeast;

//Here I converts to DbGeography, because my server side works with it.
DbGeography DbNorthwest = new DbGeography()
{
    Geography = new DbGeographyWellKnownValue()
    {
        CoordinateSystemId = 4326,
        WellKnownText = GeoLocation.ConvertLocationToPoint(new GeocodeService.Location()
        {
            Latitude = northwest.Latitude,
            Longitude = northwest.Longitude
        })
    }
};

DbGeography DbSoutheast = new DbGeography()
{
    Geography = new DbGeographyWellKnownValue()
    {
        CoordinateSystemId = 4326,
        WellKnownText = GeoLocation.ConvertLocationToPoint(new GeocodeService.Location()
        {
            Latitude = southeast.Latitude,
            Longitude = southeast.Longitude
        })
    }
};
```

And now calls to the method that should return all the objects that there location between those two points:

```
WcfClient client = new WcfClient();
var results = await client.GetEventsBetweenLocations(DbNorthwest, DbSoutheast);
```

Now I need to implement this method (which locates on the entity framework):
I dont know how to do it?

```
public IQueryable<Event> GetEventsBetweenLocations(DbGeography first, DbGeography second)
{
    //How to check if the e.GeoLocation (which is DbGeography type) is between the two locations?
    return this.Context.Events.Where(e => e.GeoLocation ...?);
}
```

I will be much thankfull if you can help me !!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution for this is to find all the points inside the bounding box defined by the NW and SE points, built using its Well-known-text representation:

```
DbGeography boundingBox = DbGeography.FromText(
        string.Format("POLYGON(({0} {1}, {3} {1}, {3} {2}, {0} {2}, {0} {1}))",
                first.Longitude,
                first.Latitude,
                second.Latitude,
                second.Longitude), 4326);
```

Then you can find your "events" that intersect this particular bounding box:

```
return this.Context.Events.Where(e => e.GeoLocation.Intersects(boundingBox));
```